# What is the proper way to style text as italic?

Tags: html, typography

Apparently, the `<i>` tag no longer tells the browser to display text in italics, but rather that the enclosed text "[is set off from the normal text for some reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i)":

> The <i> tag should represent a range of text with a different semantic meaning whose typical typographic representation is italicized.  This means a browser will typically still display its contents in italic type, but is, by definition, no longer required to.

Following this new semantic interpretation of this tag, what is the proper way to style a range of text as italic?

```
i {font-style: italic}
i .italic {font-style: italic}
span .italic {font-style: italic}
... ?
```

Let's assume I want to style the text as italic for non-semantic reasons, e.g. for aesthetic purposes. For example, I might want to italicize the first three words in every chapter (instead of using the [conventional small caps](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/capitalized-opening-lines)).

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108318/css-html-what-is-the-correct-way-to-make-text-italic

Comment: Thank you, @Ramkee. Unfortunately I can no longer delete my question, as there are answers.

Comment: Fine, I hope that link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a span class="divname" and give the "divname" a font-style:italic
or use the p tag with the same class.

I use the p tag myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
i.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

or

You should use different methods for different use cases:

If you want to emphasize a phrase use `<em>`. The `<i>` tag has a new meaning in HTML5, representing "a span of text in an alternate voice or mood". So you should use this tag for things like thoughts/asides or idiomatic phrases. The spec also suggests ship names (but no longer suggests book/song/movie names; use `<cite>` for that instead).

If the italicised text is part of a larger context, say an introductory paragraph, you should attach the CSS style to the larger element.

```
p.intro {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [`<dfn>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn) or [`<em>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em) tag. Both can make text appear ***italicized***.

```css
dfn,
em {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Demand for the creation of <dfn>right-to-left</dfn> (RTL) websites has grown over the years due to the fact that <em>Arabic</em> is the 4th most popular language globally.
```